# How do I compare date ranges in a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have data in a table like this:

```
| DateTimePurchased    | Amount |
|----------------------|--------|
| 1/1/2017  3:23:15 PM | 657    |
| 1/1/2017  3:38:29 PM | 730    |
```

And I want to run a query that outputs like this:

```
| Day   | 2017_Total | 2018_Total |
|-------|------------|------------|
| Jan 1 | 4354653    | 7686787    |
| Jan 2 | 3453634    | 6546456    |
```

etc...

How would I write the query for SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would phrase this as:

```
select month(DateTimePurchased) as mm, day(DateTimePurchased) as dd,
       sum(case when year(DateTimePurchased) = 2017 then amount end) as total_2017,
       sum(case when year(DateTimePurchased) = 2018 then amount end) as total_2018
from t
group by month(DateTimePurchased), day(DateTimePurchased)
order by mm, dd;
```

This splits the "date" into two columns, one for month and one for day.  This actually makes the results easier to work with because you sort the results more easily.

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff! I am having trouble adapting this to doing a month over month comparison. For example, if I wanted to compare February and March 2017. Obviously they don't have the same number of days, but I would want to compare Feb 1 to Mar 1, Feb 2 to Mar 2, etc... Can you help?

Comment: @Infin8Loop . . . That is a different question, so ask it as a different question.  Be sure to include the *results* that you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoffs answer is correct.

This below query gives you exactly what you asked for.

`SELECT (LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()),3)) + ' ' + CAST((DAY(DATE_ADDED)) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS [Day],
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE_ADDED) = 2017 THEN AMOUNT END) AS [2017_Total],
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE_ADDED) = 2018 THEN AMOUNT END) AS [2018_Total]
FROM TBLDATE
GROUP BY MONTH(DATE_ADDED), DAY(DATE_ADDED)
ORDER BY [Day]`

Comment: How about month over month? So the rows would be day numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) and the columns might be (Feb2017, March2017), etc... I am having trouble putting this together.

Comment: @Infin8Loop That is totally different query and different question. You can post it as new question.